# SPARQL initialization

Tags: python, initialization, sparql

I use `SPARQLWrapper` in `python` to query a web enpoint with many different querys in a loop.

So I tried to make it work like this (let `queries` hold all different queries and `result` the results):

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("url")
prefix = "prefix..."
for i in arange(1:len(queries)):
    sparql.setQuery(prefix+queries[i])
    result[i] = sparql.query().convert()
```

But this does not work. The first query I pick from the list would return the supposed result, but any other querys wouldn't.
Instead of that, I now use this:

```
for i in arange(1:len(queries)):
    [sparql,prefix] = initializeSPARQL()
    sparql.setQuery(prefix+queries[i])
    result[i] = sparql.query().convert()
```

and also

```
def initializeSPARQL():
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper("url")
    prefix = "prefix..." 
    return sparql,prefix
```

That *works* and is also not an issue of performance, since the querying itself is the bottleneck. But is there a better solution? This appears to be so wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It is strange.. because I've been checking the code, and the query() method is completely stateless, so no idea why it's failing.

With i > 1, what does result[i] contains?

May I suggest you to try the following?

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("url")
prefix = "prefix..."
results = []
for i in range(0, len(queries)):
    sparql.resetQuery()
    sparql.setQuery(prefix+queries[i])
    results[i] = sparql.query().convert()
```

Comment: Oh I did not know the resetQuery() method. I will try this and will give an update, Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but my SPARQL version does not provide the reset method : `AttributeError: SPARQLWrapper instance has no attribute 'resetQuery'` in wich version was that introduced?

Comment: not sure... but for a long time... 
http://sparql-wrapper.sourceforge.net/resources/doc/SPARQLWrapper.Wrapper.SPARQLWrapper-class.html#resetQuery

Comment: would be cool to give an answer, positive or negative, but an answer... I'm a bit tired of those users who just ask, but they do not really provide feedback about the support from others

Comment: I am sorry, that I didn't answer in any kind yet, I am still stuck with the "solution" that I provided in the beginning. It somehow works, but it seems odd to me. I have not updated the code til now, maybe there is some strange behavior caused by some version issue. As soon as I have time I will try to update my SPARQL-Wrapper code and feedback my experience. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I'm one of the developers of the library.

Your first try arises a bug. I'll check what internal data structure keeps with the previous usage to allow such way to use the library.

You second solution, even if is works, should be not the right way to do it.

As I said, I'll take a look on how to fix this.

For the future, please, submit a proper bug report to the project or an email to the mailing list.